# Serialization / Derialization of a tree structure

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer, datacontract

I'm trying to figure out the best way to save (serialize) and later open (deserialize) a tree structure. My structure is made up of various object types with different properties, but each inherits from a base abstract "Node" class.

Each node has unique ID (GUID), and has an AddSuperNode(Node nd) method that will set the parent of a node. This in turn calls other methods that allow the parent node to know what sub nodes it has. However, some nodes also utilize a **AddAuxSuperNode()** method that adds a secondary parent to the Node.

I was using binary serialization, but now I think I want to use something where I have a bit more control, and the serialized data is more accessible. I also want to retain Type information when I deserialize, and be able to serialize private values. So **DataContractSerializer** seemed like the best way to go.

I can't just serialize the root **Node** directly because of nodes having multiple parents. I do not want to create duplicate objects. So it would seem that I need to deconstruct the tree into a flat list, and then serialize that. Then after serializing that list reconstruct the tree. Does this sound right?

Like I said before each **Node** has a unique GUID identifier, but right now Nodes reference their parents/children directly and do not store their ids. I could update the **AddSuperNode()** and **AddAuxSuperNode()** methods to also update a list of parent ids to be serialized in addition to the direct references. But I'd rather only update/create this list when the object is being serialized. So i was thinking create an **UpdateSuperNodeIDRefs()** method in the node that would be called right before serialization.

The following is what I'm planning to do for serialization and deserialization of this structure. Can anyone suggestion a better/cleaner/more efficient way to do this?

**Serialization**

1) Provide the root node of the tree structure

2) Break down tree structure into a flat **Dictionary(Guid id,Node nd)** where **id** is the **guid** of **nd**.

3) Call **UpdateSuperNodeIDRefs()**; for each node to update the IDs it has saved for its parents.

4) Serialize the **Dictionary** of nodes with **DataContractSerializer**

**Deserialization**

1) Deserialize the **Dictionary** of nodes

2) Itterate through each **Node** in the **Dictionary**, reconnecting each to their parents. For any Parent IDs stored find the respective **Node**(s) in the **Dictionary** with matching ID(s) call the **AddSuperNode()** or **AddAuxSuperNode()** to re-connnect the node to its parent(s)

3) From any **Node** in the Dictionary find the root of the structure

4) Return the root **Node**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a node has multiple parents, then it isn't a tree; it is, presumably, a *graph*. However - worry not; `DataContractSerializer` can handle this for you:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[DataContract]
class Node {
    [DataMember]
    public Node AnotherNode { get; set; }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Node a = new Node(), b = new Node();
        // make it a cyclic graph, to prove reference-mode
        a.AnotherNode = b;
        b.AnotherNode = a;

        // the preserveObjectReferences argument is the interesting one here...
        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(
            typeof(Node), null, int.MaxValue, false, true, null);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            dcs.WriteObject(ms, a);
            ms.Position = 0;
            Node c = (Node) dcs.ReadObject(ms);
            // so .AnotherNode.Another node should be back to "c"
            Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(c, c.AnotherNode.AnotherNode));
        }

    }
}
```