# The deserializer has no knowlege of any type that maps to this contract

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer

I'm trying to serialize and deserialize a tree of Node objects. My abstract "Node" class as well as other abstract and concrete classes that derive from it are defined in my "Informa" project. In addition, I've created a static class in Informa for serialization  / deserialization.

First I'm deconstructing my tree into a flat list of type **Dictionary(guid,Node)** where guid is the unique id of Node.

I am able to serialize all my Nodes with out a problem. But when I try to deserialize I get the following exception.

> Error in line 1 position 227. Element
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays:Value'
>   contains data of the
>   'Informa:Building' data contract. The
>   deserializer has no knowlege of any
>   type that maps to this contract. Add
>   the type corresponding to 'Building'
>   to the list of known types - for
>   example, by usying the
>   KnownTypeAttribute or by adding it to
>   the list of known types passed to
>   DataContract Serializer.

All classes that derive from Node, including Building, have the **[KnownType(typeof(type t))]** attribute applied to them.

My serialization and deserialization methods are below:

```
public static void SerializeProject(Project project, string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        Dictionary<Guid, Node> nodeDic = DeconstructProject(project);

        Stream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);

        //serialize

        DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<Guid, Node>),"InformaProject","Informa");

        ser.WriteObject(stream,nodeDic);

        // Cleanup
        stream.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There was a problem serializing " + Path.GetFileName(filePath) + ". \n\nException:" + e.Message, "Doh!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        throw e;
    }

}



public static Project DeSerializeProject(string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        Project proj;

        // Read the file back into a stream
        Stream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

        DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<Guid, Node>), "InformaProject", "Informa");

        Dictionary<Guid, Node> nodeDic = (Dictionary<Guid, Node>)ser.ReadObject(stream);

        proj = ReconstructProject(nodeDic);        

        // Cleanup
        stream.Close();

        return proj;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There was a problem deserializing " + Path.GetFileName(filePath) + ". \n\nException:" + e.Message, "Doh!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Re flattening to a dictionary - see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736568/serialization-derialization-of-a-tree-structure/736993#736993

Comment: Answer edited to clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All classes that derive from Node,
>   including Building, have the
>   [KnownType(typeof(type t))] attribute
>   applied to them.

`KnownType` is usually applied to the *base* type - i.e.

```
[DataContract, KnownType(typeof(Building)), ...]
abstract class Node { ... }
```

(note - you can also specify the known-types in the `DataContractSerializer` constructor, without requiring attributes)

**EDIT RE YOUR REPLY**

If the framwork class doesn't know about all the derived types, then you need to specify the known types when creating the serializer:

```
[DataContract] abstract class SomeBase { }
[DataContract] class Foo : SomeBase { }
[DataContract] class Bar : SomeBase { }
...
// here the knownTypes argument is important
new DataContractSerializer(typeof(SomeBase),
      new Type[] { typeof(Foo), typeof(Bar) });
```

This can be combined with (for example) `preserveObjectReferences` etc by replacing the `null` in the previous example.

**END EDIT**

However, without something reproducible (i.e. `Node` and `Building`), it is going to be hard to help much.

The other odd thing; trees structures are *very well suited* to things like `DataContractSerializer` - there is usually no need to flatten them first, since trees can be trivially expressed in xml. Do you really need to flatten it?

---

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml;

[DataContract, KnownType(typeof(Building))]
abstract class Node {
    [DataMember]
    public int Foo {get;set;}
}
[DataContract]
class Building : Node {
    [DataMember]
    public string Bar {get;set;}
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<Guid, Node> data = new Dictionary<Guid, Node>();
        Type type = typeof(Dictionary<Guid, Node>);
        data.Add(Guid.NewGuid(), new Building { Foo = 1, Bar = "a" });
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw))
        {
            DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(type);
            dcs.WriteObject(xw, data);
        }

        string xml = sw.ToString();

        StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml);
        using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr))
        {
            DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(type);
            Dictionary<Guid, Node> clone = (Dictionary<Guid, Node>)
                dcs.ReadObject(xr);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<Guid, Node> pair in clone)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + ": " + pair.Value.Foo + "/" +
                    ((Building)pair.Value).Bar);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My tree structure allows Nodes to have multiple parents. Which complicates serialization, because I don't want to create duplicate instances.

Comment: I'm trying to define the information about my tree structure as well as methods to serialize it in one "framework" project, and then actual implementations of it in other projects.

Comment: So my framework project doesn't know all the types which might derive from Node. However Building is in my framework project, so I don't think that is the problem yet.

Answer (score 1):

Alright here's a diagram that should make things more clear. I'm developing a plugin for another program that adds relationships and properties not already included in the program. These relationships/properties are defined in my tree structure. However, I'm trying to define this structure abstractly so that I could create implementations of the plugin for different programs, as well as access the information from multiple implementations in a single "viewer" program.

My Serialize/Deserialize methods are defined in the framework, but the framework does not know about all the implementations. I was hoping I could avoid having the implementation projects pass a list of types to the save/open/serialize/deserialize methods in the framework project, but it seems I can't avoid this? I guess that make sense though, the serialize/deserialize methods must have access to the types they are deserializing.

http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/113068/informa_framework.jpg <---Larger Version
[alt text http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/113068/informa_framework.jpg](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/113068/informa_framework.jpg)

So this doesn't really explain the problem with Building, as it is a concrete class in the framework project. I think what is happening is when I serialize the DataContractSerializer has access to all the objects and their KnowType parameter and saves them correctly. But when I deserialize I create my DataContractSerializer with Dictionary as the type. So it only knows about Nodes, but not the derived classes of nodes.

```
new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<Guid, Node>))
```

I can't tell it what all the derived types are because like I said they are in other projects that the framework project doesn't know about. Soooooooo seems like the best solution is to have each implementation pass a list of Node types it uses to the serialization and deserialization methods in the framework project.

Does this make sense? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference between these two uses of the KnownTypes attribute? I didn't realize that you could/would want to specify that one class is a KnownType of another.

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Building))]
abstract class Node {
    [DataMember]
    public int Foo {get;set;}
}
[DataContract]
class Building : Node {
    [DataMember]
    public string Bar {get;set;}
}
```

---

```
[DataContract] 
[KnownType(typeof(Node))]
abstract class Node {
    [DataMember]
    public int Foo {get;set;}
}
[KnownType(typeof(Building))]
class Building : Node {
    [DataMember]
    public string Bar {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: No... [KnownType] relates to *inheritance*; the serializer needs to know that it should expect Building instances (among others) when handling Node. I'll edit my answer to clarify.