# Data Contract Serializer mandates super class to know about subclass

Tags: silverlight, wcf, oop, windows-phone-7, datacontractserializer

I got this problem,
"The deserializer has no knowlege of any type that maps to this contract"
After googling, I reached this post

[The deserializer has no knowlege of any type that maps to this contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736900/the-deserializer-has-no-knowlege-of-any-type-that-maps-to-this-contract)

where the answer says, the base class have to declare "KnownTypes" like
[DataContract, KnownType(typeof(Subclass)) ...],

If I have to declare this in my parent class, [DataContract, KnownType(typeof(Subclass))], doesn't it break the principles of OO Design that parent class doesn't have to know about subclass?

What is the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The serializer is designed in a way that, if it serializes an object, it should be able to read it back. If you attempt to serialize an object with a declared type of 'Base', but an actual type of 'Derived' (see example below), if you want to be able to read back from the serialized object an instance of 'Derived', you need to somehow annotate the XML that the instance is not of the type of which it was declared.

```
[DataContract]
public class MyType
{
    [DataMember]
    public object obj = new Derived();
}
```

The serialized version of the type would look something like the XML below:

```
<MyType>
  <obj actualType="Derived">
    <!-- fields of the derived type -->
  </obj>
</MyType>
```

When the type is being deserialized, the serializer will look at the "actualType" (not actual name) attribute, and it will have to find that type, initialize it, and set its properties. It's a potential security issue to let the serializer (with in Silverlight lives is a trusted assembly and has more "rights" than the normal user code) to create arbitrary type, so that's one reason for limiting the types which can be deserialized. And based on the design of the serializer (if we can serialize it, we should be able to deserialize it), the serialization fails for that reason as well.

Another problem with that is that the serialized data is often used to communicate between different services, in different computers, and possibly with different languages. It's possible (and often it is the case) that you have a class in a namespace in the client which has a similar *data contract* to a class in the server side, but they have different names and / or reside in different namespaces. So simply adding the CLR type name in the "actualType" attribute won't work in this scenario either (the [KnownType] attribute helps the serialzier map the data contract name / namespace to the actual CLR type). Also, if you're talking to a service in a different language / platform (i.e., Java), CLR type names don't even make sense.

Another more detailed explanation is given at the post http://www.dotnetconsult.co.uk/weblog2/PermaLink,guid,a3775eb1-b441-43ad-b9f1-e4aaba404235.aspx - it talks about [ServiceKnownType] instead of [KnownType], but the principles are the same.

Finally, about your question: does it break that OO principle? Yes, that principle is broken, that's a price to pay for being able to have lose coupling between the client and services in your distributed (service-oriented) application.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it breaks the principles of OO design. This is because SOA is about sharing contracts (the C in ABC of services) and not types, whereas OO is about type hierarchies. Think like this the client for a service may not be even in an OO language but SOA principles can still be applied. How the mapping is done on server side is an implementation issue.