# RuntimeType:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System' is not expected

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer

Ok so I got DataContractSerializer working with my object graph. See my previous questions for more information.

[Serialization / Derialization of a tree structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736568/serialization-derialization-of-a-tree-structure)

[The deserializer has no knowlege of any type that maps to this contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736900/the-deserializer-has-no-knowlege-of-any-type-that-maps-to-this-contract)

However, one of my fields, **_UserPropertyDefinitions**, is defined as shown below.. It defines a list of custom  properties that this user can add to objects in the data structure. The string is a unique key to identify the property, and Type is the type of the property which is always a primative type like Bool, Int, String etc etc..

Each object has a corresponding **Dictionary(String key, Object value)** collection to store the values it has set for any of the "User Properties"

```
[DataMember]
private Dictionary<string, Type> _UserPropertyDefinitions;
```

My object graph serializes fine when this property is an empty collection, yet once I add a custom property to this collection I get the following exception when trying to serialize with DataContractSerializer.

> Type 'System.RuntimeType' with data
>   contract name
>   'RuntimeType:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System'
>   is not expected. Add any types not
>   known statically to the list of known
>   types - for example, by using the
>   KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by
>   adding them to the list of known types
>   passed to DataContractSerializer.

If I remove the DataMember attribute for this field the I can serialize/deserialize with out getting an exception, but of course I loose the settings I've created in this field.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response ;-p Either Type.GetType() or Assembly.GetType()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that `Type` isn't going to serialize very well - and arguably it doesn't belong in a data-contract anyway, since (being implementation specific) it defeats one of the main aims of a data-contract...

However, I expect the best approach would be to swap that for a `Dictionary<string,string>`, using the `Type`'s `AssemblyQualifiedName` or `FullName`.

Comment: Geeze Marc don't you have any real work to do? :-) But seriously I really appreciate the help. So basically I'd store the name of the Type, and then later retrieve the real Type from the name?

I know how to find the Type's name, but how would I retrieve a Type later when I only know the name?

Comment: @Marc Gravell how would you retrieve the type when you only have the name if it isn't a known farmework type ,
would you also send the entire assembly some how ?

Comment: @eran well, an AssemblyQualifiedName isn't "just" a name, but yes it is problematic, especially if the assemblies are different. If the two implementations can categorise their known types,maybe an enum would suffice? In protobuf-net, for serialising Type I let the user provide an implementation for Type <==> string, so they can map it manually.

Comment: @MarcGravell i need to pass a custom Type from my client to a wcf service ,
this can't be done since the service does not know the Type i'm sending .
any work arounds come to mind for this scenario ?